# Why pandas is giving me output : convertbinarytoasc.py <infile> <outfile> when doing "import pandas as pd"

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, import, pip

I'm trying to use pandas lib in one of my script.

here is the very few first lines :

```
import numpy as np 
print("numpy ok")
import pandas as pd
print("pandas ok")
```

and I keep having this output :

```
numpy ok
convertbinarytoasc.py <infile> <outfile>
PS C:\py
```

If I do :

```
import numpy as np 
print("numpy ok")
#import pandas as pd
print("pandas ok")
```

then the output is :

```
numpy ok
pandas ok
PS C:\py
```

I found nothing on web about that.
using python 3.9 32bit/64bit.
do the same in other environment

Script is running in VScode, used pip to install stuff

Anybody knows about this?

Thk for helping me :)

Comment: You need to add more details about the problem.

Comment: wich details do you need? version? pandas is 1.4.1

Comment: I have the following packages isntalled :
numpy 1.22.2
pandas 1.4.1
pip 21.2.4
Python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz 2021.3
setuptools 58.1.0
six 1.16.0

I'm using windows 10 & vscode.
Python scripts run well.

Comment: you need to add more lines of your current script... these 4 lines of code aren't enough to find the problem.

Comment: @gajendragarg
Ok, the script works perfect if I remove the line : 
import pandas as pd.

with code :
 

`import numpy as np `
`print("numpy ok")`
`#import pandas as pd`
`print("pandas ok")`

output is :
 
ReadToRamPd.py
**numpy ok**
**pandas ok**
PS C:\py>

the problem is related to this import pandas line

I have nothing more yet in the script

Comment: @Oo87 Check if it's wrong pandas (like your own `pandas.py`): `import pandas; print(pandas.__file__)`

Comment: @phd what do you mean? I have no panda.py in local.
import pandas; make already the problem

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the pandas or switch the environment? And what about if you only reserve `import pandas as pd print("pandas ok")`

Comment: @Steven-MSFT I did change envronment, doe the same. doing import pandas only makes only : convertbinarytoasc.py <infile> <outfile>
PS C:\py

Comment: I did change the folder where the script is, and it works well now... I have no idea why it's not working within the original folder.

Comment: @Oo87 What's the name of the original folder?

Answer (score 1):

@phd

I did check, and I found an old script named "csv.py" in the same folder. this script seems to be loaded by the pandas lib. I Removed the script from the folder and pandas works perfect.

Comment: `pandas` imports [builtin module `csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Learn from the debacle: **NEVER** name you modules the same name as modules/packages from the standard library or well-known 3rd-party modules/packages. For example, never name your modules `email.py` or `test.py`.

Comment: thx for the tip